# ASP.NET Core - Create custom model validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

In previous versions of ASP.NET MVC the way to add custom validation to your model was by implementing the `IValidatableObject` and implementing your own `Validate()` method.

Here's what I have implemented:

```cs
public class BestModelEver: IValidatableObject 
{
    public DateTime? Birthday { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) 
    {
        if (Birthday.HasValue) 
        {
          yield return new ValidationResult("Error message goes here");
        }
    }
}
```

Is this still the recommended way of adding custom validation to a model in ASP.NET Core?  Using `IValidatableObject` takes on a `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` dependency.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There are two ways to do custom model validation in ASP.NET Core:

- A custom attribute subclassed from `ValidationAttribute`. This is useful when you want to apply custom business logic to a particular model *property* with an attribute.
- Implementing `IValidatableObject` for class-level validation. Use this instead when you need to do validation on an entire model at once.

The [documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/models/validation.html#alternatives-to-built-in-attributes) has examples of both. In your case, `IValidatableObject` would probably be the best approach.

Comment: I was looking for a custom validation section in their docs, but it looks like I missed it.  Thanks!