# Validate a model with filter Attribute

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-mvc-filters

I am practicing about validations in attributes for DRY reasons but I get some examples for Web Api and I do not know if there is a way to return a View with the invalid data and modelstate errors instead of BadRequestObjectResult used in API.

I have read the official documentation about it but I do not understand how it is implemented in the case of a view.

I am using a basic model with 2 inputs to add data in EF Core Entity to test this attribute filter. My objective is get something generic for this case because I understand it for Web Api.

**Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.**

I want to change this in the IActionResult:

```
if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    return View(ModelState)
```

to something like this attribute class:

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // I know that this line indicates a BadRequestObjectResult
            // but I don't know how to returning like view if
            // the Web App use razor pages

            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
        }

    base.OnActionExecuting(context);
}
```

This is the actual response with the example (But I want to use the MVC pages to return the errors and the model data):

```
{ "LastName":["The LastName field is required."],"FirstName":["The FirstName"]}
```

Comment: so instead of sending it from controller, you want to create filter for it ?

Comment: are you sure inheriting from `ActionFilterAttribute` makes sense?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I implement custom model validation in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332712/how-do-i-implement-custom-model-validation-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: @Vishalmodi Yes sir but don't returning like BadRequest()

Comment: @JohnB This is the example code from some sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating Validation filter, you do not need to do anything inside your `ValidateModelAttribute`. you just need to check `ModelState.IsValid`, so it will work globally and it will return view same as you write it on controller's action.

Without writing any extra code, it will return your view with error.

```
 [ValidateModel]
 public IActionResult Index(Test t)
 {
    return View(t);
 }

public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }

}
```

Comment: I already found my mistake. As you said it is not necessary to add extra code. although if necessary always return the data properly. Thanks for your help