# How to require the filling of an Entity attribute dependent on a condition - ASP NET Core MVC and Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want `Item2` to be mandatory only if `Item.code` = "yes". The `InputModel` is used in the `Register` at `Register.cshtml.cs`.

```
public class Item
{
  [Required]
   public string Id{ get; set; }
  [Required]
   public string desc{ get; set; }
  [Required]
   public string code{ get; set; }
}

public class Item2
{
  [Required]
    public string Id{ get; set; }
  [Required]
    public string slug{ get; set; }
}


public class InputModel
{
  [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

  [Required]
    public string Password{ get; set; }

  [Required]
    public Item Item { get; set; }

   public Item2 Item2 { get; set; }
}
```

I intended to do something like this, IN InputModel

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
            {
                if (Item.code=="yes")
                {
                    ===> set Item2 Required
                }
            }
```

This is the logic, can anyone help?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38332905/4051181) to a different question might be helpful for you.

Comment: Please provide more details. What kind of validation do you have now? Do you use additional tools, e.g., FluentValidation?

Comment: No. I only use asp net core with mvc and entity framework. I am changing the registration page. And I intend to apply that rule.

Comment: Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to try [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/), which was mentioned in the comments. It is really worth to take a bit of time to research it. Let's imagine you've downloaded it and want to implement your validation.

```
public class InputModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Password{ get; set; }

    public Item Item { get; set; }

    public Item2 Item2 { get; set; }
}



public class InputModelValidator
    : AbstractValidator<InputModel>
{
    public InputModelValidator() 
    {
        RuleFor(request => request.Item2)
        .NotNull()
        .When(request =>
              request.Item != null
              && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Item.Code)
              && request.Item.Code == "yes")
        .WithMessage("Item2 is mandatory if Item.code == 'yes'");
    }
 }
```

Still, there are many different ways of doing it, but I'm using FluentValidation in my project.

Comment: I haven't noticed that you've written that you are not going to use any additional packages. Yeah, so it means that my answer is not the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

First, in the `Item2` class, remove the `[Required]` attribute. Then, in the InputModel, you could implement the IValidatableObject, then Validate the values. Code as below:

```
    public class Item
    {
        [Required]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string desc { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string code { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item2
    { 
        public string Id { get; set; } 
        public string slug { get; set; }
    }

    public class InputModel: IValidatableObject
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Item Item { get; set; }

        public Item2 Item2 { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (Item.code.ToLower() == "yes")
            {
                if(Item2.Id==null)
                    yield return new ValidationResult($"Item2 ID is required!", new[] { "Item2.Id" });
                
                if (Item2.slug == null) 
                    yield return new ValidationResult($"Item2 slug is required!", new[] { "Item2.slug" }); 
            }
        }
    }
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]